# No matching function for call to function error

Tags: c++

When I am trying to call my function, I get the error:

> expected expression []. What do I put inside the []? I put count for each array but then another error saying Undefined symbol: modifiedSortGPA(double, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, int)

```
void modifiedSortGPA(double, int, string, int); //function prototype

...

// my arrays
int netID[NUM_ELMTS]; // Original netID array
string major[NUM_ELMTS]; // Original major array
double GPA[NUM_ELMTS]; // Original GPA array

double sortedGPAbyGPA[NUM_ELMTS]; // GPA array, sorted by GPA
int sortedNetIDbyGPA[NUM_ELMTS];
string sortedMajorbyGPA[NUM_ELMTS];
    
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) //populating my arrays
{
    GPA[i] = sortedGPAbyGPA[i];
    netID[i] = sortedNetIDbyGPA[i];
    major[i] = sortedMajorbyGPA[i];
}

modifiedSortGPA(sortedGPAbyGPA[], sortedNetIDbyGPA[], sortedMajorbyGPA[], count); //function call in main

...

void modifiedSortGPA(double array1[], int array2[], string array3[], int size) //function
{
    int startScan, minIndex, minValue;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array1[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (array1[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array1[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        array1[minIndex] = array1[startScan];
        array1[startScan] = minValue;
    }    
}
```

I tried to make sure that there were no typos in my prototype, my function call, and my function definition. I am expecting my function to print the sorted arrays.

Comment: `void modifiedSortGPA(double, int, string, int); //function prototype` `void modifiedSortGPA(double array1[], int array2[], string array3[], int size) //function` Spot the difference.

Comment: A double[] is different from a single double. Same goes with int[] and int and string[] and string.

Comment: When I get a problem like this, I take the declaration and paste it on the line above the definition. Then line up all of the pieces for easy comparison and use the ol' Mk I eyeball to scan both lines for the mistake. That or move the definition ahead of first use and delete the declaration.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to make sure that there were no typos in my prototype, my function call, and my function definition.

And yet, you did not succeed in that, because your function's *declaration* DOES NOT match your function's *definition*.  The values you are passing into the function DO NOT match the *declaration*, hence the error.

In your declaration, the 1st parameter takes a single `double`, the 2nd parameter takes a single `int`, and the 3rd parameter takes a single `string`.

But, in your definition, the 1st parameter takes a `double[]` array, the 2nd parameter takes an `int[]` array, and the 3rd parameter takes a `string[]` array.

You need to fix the declaration to match the definition, eg:

```
void modifiedSortGPA(double[], int[], string[], int); //function prototype
```

---

On a side note: arrays are 0-indexed, meaning the 1st index is 0 and the last index is 1 less than the element count. But your `for` loop that is populating the arrays with data is going past the end of the arrays by 1 element, which is *undefined behavior* . It is trying to access elements at `count` as the last index, but the last index is `count-1` instead. You need to fix that, by use `<` instead of `<=` in the loop condition, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) //populating my arrays
```